# How to get the website error count in chromium cef3

Tags: delphi, chromium, tchromium

For some reasons, I need to get error count of a webiste. I've been checking google for a while now but can't find any solutions. [image: chromium view when pressed F12]. In the picture, I want the value 5. How can I do it?

Comment: My experience with chromium unfortunately is very poor. I found many entries by searching for "ErrorCount" on https://cs.chromium.org/
- Thanks to Nasreddine Galfout for preventing me from beeing Downvoted under 50 reputation :D

Comment: @fisi-pjm Welcome to Stack Overflow. once you get how this site works. I'm sure you will love the quality and appreciate the effort made by the community to keep it high.

Comment: You need to enable the remote debugging in that browser to get all the information available in the DevTools. Assuming you use CEF4Delphi to embed a chromium browser in your Delphi application you would have to set the GlobalCEFApp.RemoteDebuggingPort property before the GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess call in the DPR file. 

The DOMVisitor sets GlobalCEFApp.RemoteDebuggingPort to 9000. Run it and navigate to http://localhost:9000/ using another browser to start debugging.

Read this for more info about the protocol you will use : https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: @fisi-pjm See [50 reputation points to make comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252133/62576) for an explanation of why the rep is needed.